# MySQL Subquery to pull results that meet multiple column data-points

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-workbench

I would like to build a query to pull through results that meet multiple column results from another table.

I have a Table titled 'Engagements' and a Table titled 'Entertainers'. Engagement contains CustomerID and EntertainerId. Entertainers contains EntertainerID and EntertainerName.

Question: List the CustomerIDs for the customers who have booked shows with Entertainer X, Entertainer Y, and Entertainer Z.

I have tried the solution below, but 1) I don't believe that joins are appropriate in the subquery? and 2) Having 2+ criteria within the same column (i.e. having booked entertainers X, Y, and Z) seems to be causing me issues. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Engagements.CustomerID
FROM Database.Engagements
WHERE Engagements.CustomerID = ALL (SELECT CustomerID
FROM Database.Engagements
JOIN Database.Entertainers USING (EntertainerID)
WHERE EntertainerName = "X"
OR EntertainerName = "Y"
OR EntertainerName = "Z";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just count the number of distinct entertainers, if it is 3 then the customer booked with all three entertainers

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Engagements
JOIN Entertainers USING (EntertainerID)
WHERE EntertainerName IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Engagements.EntertainerID) = 3
```

Comment: Do you know how this would look in a subquery form?

Comment: using 3 subqueries, so that `CustomerID IN ( ... A ) AND CustomerID IN ( ... B ) AND CustomerID  IN ( ... C )`